# eror when parsing json android no data when run

Tags: android, json

This is my code how i use to load data with json..

```
client.get(URL, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject obj) {
                try {

                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                        JSONArray cest = obj.getJSONArray("list");

                        String z = "";
                        if (cest != null) {
                            int array = cest.length();
                            mDetail = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
                            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            Date dateOrder = new Date();

                            for (int i = 0; i < array; i++) {

                                try {
                                    dateOrder = formatter.parse(cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("OrderDate"));
                                } catch (ParseException e) {}

                                mDetail.add(new OrderDetailsInfo(UUID.fromString(cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("OrderID"))
                                        , dateOrder,
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("BrancId"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("DCBranchID"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("OrderDocNo"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("SubdealerID"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("DocOrderNo"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("OrderDocNoAlt"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("SalesChannelID"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("MarketingProgramID"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("MDMarketingProgramID"),
                                        cest.getJSONObject(i).getString("PriceListID")));
                            }

                            OrderDetailsAdapter adapter = new OrderDetailsAdapter(getActivity(), mDetail);
                            setListAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Refreshed: " + cest.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } //if (cast != null) {
                    } //if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                // Probable causes: no internet permission, no internet connection
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "error: onFailure: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

    }
```

When i run this there no eror but the data cannot be load..

What wrong with my code.?

Somebody please help me..

Comment: Add some log in your *catch()* block !!

Comment: can you help me with example sir.?

Comment: Add `Log.e("ERROR",  e.getMessage());` or `e.printStackTrace();` to all your catch blocks. And show us the Logcat.

Comment: 10-10 14:55:06.680    3513-3513/com.murnimotor.salesmanager D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-10 14:55:06.700    3513-3513/com.murnimotor.salesmanager D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow

Comment: Filter your LogCat to show only errors, not all the log.

Comment: 10-10 15:14:42.865  14824-14824/com.murnimotor.salesmanager E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
10-10 15:14:42.865  14824-14824/com.murnimotor.salesmanager E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013
10-10 15:14:48.025  14824-14824/com.murnimotor.salesmanager E/ERROR﹕ No value for BrancId

Comment: this is from adb logs : 
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 4df124be5bd84fe5: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for 
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 4df124be5bd84fe5: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
DeviceMonitor: ExecutionException getting info for device 4df124be5bd84fe5

Comment: First check whether you are getting response, you can take the help of `debugging`!